# Is it possible to use NextCloud to download the private folders and SVN for downloading few private specific files for dotfiles with dotdrop?

Tags: git, svn, git-submodules, dotfiles

Sorry if my question is inappropriate to this forum. I do not know if `dotfiles` is relevant to Stackoverflow or if it should be posted on Super User or Unix and Linux Stack Exchange.

I migrated from Arch Linux with KDE to Endeavour OS with i3. Look at [@ReekyMarko](https://gitlab.com/ReekyMarko)'s [dotfiles](https://gitlab.com/ReekyMarko/dotfiles). I found his dotfiles interesting because of `dotdrop`, `deploy.sh` and `pkglist` to ease the installation of both home and `root` folders. I used to install only the home folder, using git commands or `stow`. I found hard to install the root folder into root system with git, so I had to copy manually and install manually each package. The Atlassian tutorial "[The best way to store your dotfiles: A bare Git repository](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/02/best-way-to-store-dotfiles-git-bare-repo/)" is not efficient in case of the `root` folder. I would like to keep my dotfiles public, so I could share to the community.

I know how to use `dotdrop`, using `curl` for `deploy.sh` with Shell on the terminal. But there are two problems:

- I have few private personal folders as applications, documents, extensions, fonts, images, pictures, projects, graphic design, programming, templates and web design. I know you suggest me to create the private repository, add `git-submodules`, but Git* limits until 500MB. I know `git-lfs`. You must know Git* is not a good alternative for backing the files up, like Mega and NextCloud. I do not know if it is possible to use NextCloud to download the private folders with `config-home.yaml`, `dotdrop` and `deploy.sh`.
- In spite of Git* not being a good alternative for backup, I can back all the fonts up to a private repository, add sub-module. But as I do not want to download the whole fonts repository, I will use Subversion to download only some specific fonts for `~./local/shares/fonts`. Then I do not know if it is possible to use Subversion for `git-submodule` and with `config-home.yaml`, `dotdrop` and `deploy.sh`.

#### Extra

- I also would like to know if it is download and install `rbenv-installer` and `nvm` (for installing Nodejs versions) in the home folder with `dotdrop` and `deploy.sh`.
- I would like to know how to resync automatically per month all these home and root folders to dotfiles with `dotdrop` via git, and the personal files to NextCloud.

Comment: Did you ever ascertain what the answer to this is?